# How to use compatibleImage to make drawing images faster in java2D?

Tags: bufferedimage, java-2d, drawimage

I'm writing a game in Java2D, and it runs smoothly on my computer and another computer I tested it on. However on another computer, with decent specs and same java settings, it is extremely slow. I'm pretty sure that I narrowed it down to the g.drawImage() command. After doing some research, I found that someone made a method that compiled some things that he found worked for increasing speed, the method is:

```
public BufferedImage toCompatibleImage(BufferedImage image) {
    // obtain the current system graphical settings
    GraphicsConfiguration gfx_config = GraphicsEnvironment
            .getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getDefaultScreenDevice()
            .getDefaultConfiguration();



     //if image is already compatible and optimized for current system
     //settings, simply return it

    if (image.getColorModel().equals(gfx_config.getColorModel())) {

        return image;
    }

    // image is not optimized, so create a new image that is
    BufferedImage new_image = gfx_config.createCompatibleImage(
            image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(), Transparency.TRANSLUCENT);

    // get the graphics context of the new image to draw the old image on
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) new_image.getGraphics();

    // actually draw the image and dispose of context no longer needed
    g2d.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
    g2d.dispose();

    // return the new optimized image
    // System.out.println(image.getColorModel());
    return new_image;
}
```

I am confused how you use this method. I've done:
1) Calling it just when creating the image from a png using Image.IO.

```
BufferedImage img = toCompatibleImage(theLoadedImage);
```

and then later in the paintComponent(Graphics g) method simply calling

```
 Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
 g.drawImage(img, x, y, null);
```

2) Calling it in each repaint like so:

```
 Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
 g.drawImage(toCompatibleImage(theLoadedImage), x, y, null);
```

Both of which do not seem to do much of anything except nominal changes in FPS, the first method being slightly faster. I have no idea if I am using this right, so help and basic explanation would be really helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the first method, it is enough to convert it once.

A compatible image stores the pixels internally in the same format as your video card, so they don't have to be converted every time they are drawn.